# Global variables Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, variables, tabs, ionic2, injectable

I'm having some difficulties with Ionic 2 and setting up global variables. The structure of my app is as follows:

```
Main app
  |
  |--- Page1 (Info)
  |--- Page2 (Map)
  |--- Page3 (List)
         |
         |--- ItemTabsPage
                |
                |---tab1
                |---tab2
                |---tab3
```

My intention is to show a list in *Page3*, and once one item is selected, to show additional information in tabs.

I send the information from Page 3 to the page with the tabs using:

```
itemTapped(event, item) {
    this.nav.push(ItemTabsPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }
```

The problem is that I can't do the same to send the info to the child tabs. I would like to show different information depending on which item is selected. I have tried defining an injectable *globalVars.js* to store the value in a variable:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalVars {

  constructor(myGlobalVar) {
    this.myGlobalVar = "";
  }

  setMyGlobalVar(value) {
    this.myGlobalVar = value;
  }

  getMyGlobalVar() {
    return this.myGlobalVar;
  }

}
```

and then updating the code of itemTapped in the list as follows:

```
itemTapped(event, item) {
        this.nav.push(ItemTabsPage, {
          item: item
        });
        this.globalVars.setMyGlobalVar(item);
      }
```

However, I always get the same error:

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMyGlobalVar' of undefined
```

The code for *page3* is:

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ItemService} from '../services/ItemService';
import {ItemTabsPage} from '../item/item-tabs/item-tabs';
import {GlobalVars, setMyGlobalVar} from '../../providers/globalVars';

import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/item-list/item-list.html',
  providers: [ItemService]
})

export class ItemListPage {

  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController], [NavParams], [Http]];
  }

  constructor(nav, navParams, http, globalVars) {
    this.nav = nav;
    // If we navigated to this page, we will have an item available as a nav param
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
    this.http = http;
    //this.items = null;
    this.globalVars = globalVars;


    this.http.get('https://website-serving-the-info.com/items.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.items = data.items;
        },
      err => {
          console.log("Oops!");
    });

  }

  itemTapped(event, item) {
    this.nav.push(ItemTabsPage, {
      item: item
    });
    this.globalVars.setMyGlobalVar(item);
  }
}
```

Anyone have any suggestion? My Ionic installation is:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
OS: Distributor ID: LinuxMint Description:  Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa 
Node Version: v5.11.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. And some of the other answers will work, but the Ionic team is recommending you not use globals via a globals file. Instead, they recommend the use of `Providers` (as you're attempting to do).

You're provider is missing the actual variable declaration.

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalVars {
    myGlobalVar: string = ''  // this is the line you're missing

    constructor(myGlobalVar) {
        this.myGlobalVar = "";
    }
}
```

You should also note that you are not exporting the function `setMyGlobalVar()`. You are exporting the class `GlobalVars` which contains the function `setMyGlobalVar()`.

I believe if you make those changes it should work.

edit
I'd also be careful of this line `this.globalVars = globalVars;` in your `Page3`. This will cause a rewrite of your `globalVars` each time `Page3` is created.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I use is to create a file app/global.ts

```
export var global = {
    myvar : 'myvar 01',
    myfunction : function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
};
```

Then import and use freely in other classes:

```
import {global} from "../../global";

constructor() {        
    global.myfunction('test');
}
```

and if you want to use this global to component HTML page as below

```
    export class HomePage {
        Global: any = Global;
```

now it is available in HTML as below

```
    <div [style.display]="Global.splash ? 'flex': 'none'" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same scenario, and would like to share my approach.

my understanding is that, in ionic2, the injection is implemented as instance. which means each time you enter a page, a new instance of the injection is created.

so direct access to a static value does not fit here; you have to somehow bridge the gap.

my approach goes as this:

you still defined a static value in your service provider, yet you define instance "getter", and "setter" for that value.

in your page implementation, you inject the service as a parameter of the constructor.

in the constructor, you have to "new" an instance of the service; and call the  "getter", and "setter". see my code snippets below:

```
export class TransSender {
   static _count:number = 0;
   static _pushed:number = 0;
   ...

   public static setter(count:number, pushed:number,...) {
        TransSender._count = count;
        TransSender._pushed = pushed;
   }
   public get count(){
        return TransSender._count;
   }
   public get pushed(){
        return TransSender._pushed;
   }
   ... 
}
```

I actually provide a static collective setter for the service to get value from backend in a static way.

my page implementation runs likes this

```
import {TransSender} ...;

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/basics/basics.html',  
    providers: [TransSender]
})

export class Page {
    ...  
    constructor(tSender: TransSender,...) {  
        ...
        tSender = new TransSender();
        TransSender.setter(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
        console.log(tSender.count);
    } 
}
```

in your display (html), your will refer to tSender rather than TransSender

this might look a bit stupid. yet I can not find any other solution.

with the release of ionic2 Beta9, bootstrap was re-introduced into the frame. so I am exploring new possibilities

cheers

Answer (score 0):

In your class ItemListPage, try this static parameters method before your constructor:

```
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController], [NavParams], [Http], [GlobalVars]];
  }
```

I am thinking that you are setting your globalVars variable in the constructor to 'undefined' and therefore you cannot call a function on something that is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I add [GlobalVars] the app becames blank and it doesn't work...

Comment: I uploaded the code to https://github.com/realjumy/menuPlusTabs because there's still something failing but I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to inject the GlobalVars provider incorrectly in ItemLisyPage.